# Why doesn't the state change to 'tapped' when I tap it (flutter - dart)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a piano tiles game (flutter - dart) and I have just randomised the tiles. However, the game isn't working. The state of the first note I tap doesn't get the status 'tapped', but the song has started to play (see code below). I have imported all the necessary packages so that isn't the problem. I also does not get any sort of error of flutter.

This the new code for randomising the tiles. When I hardcode the tiles, the game does work.

```
final number = new List<int>.generate(300, (i) => i + 1);

var rng = new Random();
final place = new List.generate(300, (_) => rng.nextInt(3));

final noteListStart = new List<Note>.generate(number.length, (i) => Note(number[i],place[i]));

final List<Note> noteListEnd = [
Note(300, -1), Note(301, -1),Note(302, -1),Note(303, -1)
];

final initList = List<Note>.from(noteListStart)..addAll(noteListEnd);

List<Note> initNotes() {
  return
    initList;
}
```

```
List<Note> notes = initNotes(); // already declared in a previous class

void _onTap(Note note) {
    bool areAllPreviousTapped = notes
        .sublist(0, note.orderNumber)
        .every((n) => n.state == NoteState.tapped);
    print(areAllPreviousTapped);

    if (currentNoteIndex == 0) {
      audioCache.play('TheForce.mp3');
    }

    if (areAllPreviousTapped) {
      if (!hasStarted) {
        setState(() => hasStarted = true);
        animationController.forward();
      }
      setState(() {
        note.state = NoteState.tapped; // the .tapped is declared in another class
        ++points;
      });
    }
  }
```

The code where I call _onTap:

```
_drawLine(int lineNumber) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Line(
        lineNumber: lineNumber,
        currentNotes: notes.sublist(currentNoteIndex, currentNoteIndex + 5),
        onTileTap: _onTap,
        animation: animationController,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Can someone please help me? I have no clue what went wrong.

Comment: you mean  `print(areAllPreviousTapped);` not getting printed?

Comment: yes, that is the problem in short

Comment: I think it has something to do with tha fact that the tiles are now randomised, is that possible?

Comment: Show us the code where you call `_onTap`.

Comment: I would suggest you remove all the if else code in onTap function, and check is the song played?

Comment: The song is still playing.

Comment: maybe you have other code to play the song?